# Bush like flower plant. What is it?

Tags: identification, houseplants

Does this plant require full sun?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please: one question per plant (or you will not be able to accept an answer).

Comment: oh! I think I cannot ask more than 3 questions per day. And didn't want to push older questions further. So I asked them at once cause I have 3-4 more plants to be identified. Should I leave it be or break them apart? @GiacomoCatenazzi

Comment: I would break a part. You may have more question per day (now that your reputation are higher, but the exact number depends on various parameters). You can just queue the question for next days, so that also for us it is easier [limited time, especially if we need to find relevant links]

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Done

Comment: 4-K the answer to your “should I break it up” question lies in the Stack Exchange system. If you remember that all Q/As are intended to help you *now* and more readers *in the future*, a combined question doesn’t make sense. All posts that are a hodge-podge of multiple id questions would be closed as too broad.

Comment: @Stephie I made them individual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a begonia, probably a large wax begonia. I've grown them outdoors in full sun to partial shade, and have one in my basement right now that is doing rather poorly in full shade. Indoors, I'd grow it in an east window or maybe the southwest corner of a south window (so that it gets morning sun). If it begins dropping leaves, you could move into full sun, if you have it.

More important, I think, is watering. This is a semi-succulent, so don't over-water (maybe every two weeks at most during the depths of winter).

Comment: Can I place them outside in winter? Or strictly inside?

Comment: Begonias are tender perennials and will die at 0C/32F, so I'd keep this plant inside unless you're in a sub-tropical/tropical area.

Comment: The stems of the plant are snapping easily. Is this normal for this plant to be that tender? Also all the flowers have dried and many leaves fallen.

Comment: What kind of light are you giving it? It can be normal for a begonia's stems to snap - sometimes, just lightly touching them can cause it (in winter). The goal here should be to keep it alive through the winter rather than keeping it looking garden-worthy. The one I have in my basement looks horrible (way too dim for it), but will be going under artificial light in a week or so when I start my seeds for this spring. It should perk up quite a bit then. I'll prune it a bit when it goes under lights, then again in late March to give it a more pleasing form. .

Comment: I am giving it bright indirect light. The plant is giving new leaves however so it is not dead as I thought previously. But if this plant breaks so easily, how am I gonna repot it?

Comment: Some breakage is pretty much inevitable. You could take this opportunity to shape your plant for the spring and summer now, rather than waiting until March or April- cut it shorter than it is (maybe 50-70% shorter) to encourage the new growth on the short stems so that when you repot the plant it will be less prone to breaking. This will result in a well-shaped plant for the new growing season. A good method to avoid breakage is to have a helper when you repot - one person holds the pot, the other loosely holds the plant. Turn the pot over and thump it/jerk it upwards to release the plant.

Comment: Note that you can reshape the plant over several weeks, if removing all long branches now also removes all of the new growth. You don't want to do that. Maybe cut half of the plant back now, wait for new growth to appear on the cut portions, then cut back the rest of the old growth.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Jurp. I will repot this when it is required like you have mentioned. Right now the pot is good size for this.